# Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I keep getting this error at referring to `'url'` in this block of code.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined.

Although the URL is defined clearly in a variable above the ajax.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$.ajax({
url: url,
dataType: 'jsonp',
cache: true,
jsonpCallback: 'wCallback_1'
});
```

Here is the full code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(function () {
// Specify the location code and units (f or c)
var location = 'SPXX0550';
var u = 'c';


// Run the query (pull data from rss feed)
var query = 'SELECT * FROM rss WHERE url="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss/' + location + '_' + u + '.xml"';
var cacheBuster = Math.floor((new Date().getTime()) / 1200 / 1000);
var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query) + '&format=json&_nocache=' + cacheBuster;
});

window['wCallback_1'] = function(data) {
    var info = data.query.results.item.forecast[0];
    $('#wIcon').append('<img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/' + info.code + '.gif" width="34" height="34" title="' + info.text + '" />');
    $('#wTemp').html(info.temp + '&deg;' + (u.toUpperCase()));
    $('#wText').html(info.text);
};

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: true,
    jsonpCallback: 'wCallback_1'
});
```

Comment: You have your ajax call outside of the scope of your ready function. So the ajax call attempts to execute before the document is ready, rendering the `url` variable as undefined, being that it is compiled at the execution of the document ready state.

Comment: `url` is **local** to the `ready` callback. Why don't you put all your code inside the callback? And additionally, at the moment you execute `$.ajax`, the `ready` callback wasn't called yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you define and populate `url` in the block of code surrounded by `$(function() { })`, that runs when the document is loaded.

However, the code following it (where you try to use `url`) is run immediately (before the document has loaded).

Just put all the code inside the `$(function() { })` block and it will work fine...

```
$(function () {
    // Specify the location code and units (f or c)
    var location = 'SPXX0550';
    var u = 'c';


    // Run the query (pull data from rss feed)
    var query = 'SELECT * FROM rss WHERE url="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss/' + location + '_' + u + '.xml"';
    var cacheBuster = Math.floor((new Date().getTime()) / 1200 / 1000);
    var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query) + '&format=json&_nocache=' + cacheBuster;

    window['wCallback_1'] = function(data) {
        var info = data.query.results.item.forecast[0];
        $('#wIcon').append('<img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/' + info.code + '.gif" width="34" height="34" title="' + info.text + '" />');
        $('#wTemp').html(info.temp + '&deg;' + (u.toUpperCase()));
        $('#wText').html(info.text);
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: true,
        jsonpCallback: 'wCallback_1'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank-you for the explanation and answer.  Being new to Javascript this has not only solved the issue, but has also has been a common mistake I have been making!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `url` is outside of the scope of your `$.ajax` call. You need to move it inside the ready handler, or make url available as a global

```
$(function () {
    // Specify the location code and units (f or c)
    var location = 'SPXX0550';
    var u = 'c';


    // Run the query (pull data from rss feed)
    var query = 'SELECT * FROM rss WHERE url="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss/' + location + '_' + u + '.xml"';
    var cacheBuster = Math.floor((new Date().getTime()) / 1200 / 1000);
    var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query) + '&format=json&_nocache=' + cacheBuster;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: true,
        jsonpCallback: 'wCallback_1'
    });    
});

window['wCallback_1'] = function(data) {
    var info = data.query.results.item.forecast[0];
    $('#wIcon').append('<img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/' + info.code + '.gif" width="34" height="34" title="' + info.text + '" />');
    $('#wTemp').html(info.temp + '&deg;' + (u.toUpperCase()));
    $('#wText').html(info.text);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `url` is defined inside a function so it is bound to that execution context (scope). You need the `$.ajax` call to be in the same execution context. If you move it into the function, then it will work.